# Task Cancellation and TaskContinuationOptions

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I was just introduced to Tasks (TPL) yesterday, and so I tried to do a little sample project in order to develop an understanding of how to use them.

My sample project is setup with a start button that begins incrementing a progressbar.  A second button to cancel the task.  A text box to report when the continuation using the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion is called, and a text box to report when the continuation using the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled is called.

I can create and execute a Task, but canceling it in a way that lets a continuation with the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled flag to fire, has been a problem.

I create the tasks as follows:

```
private void StartTask()
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

    Task task = null;
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(tokenSource), tokenSource.Token);

    //A list<CancellationTokenSource> so that I can cancel the task when clicking a button on the UI Thread.
    MyTasks.Add(tokenSource);

    Task completed = task.ContinueWith(result => TaskCompleted(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    Task canceled = task.ContinueWith(result => TaskCanceled(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
}
```

I cancel the task as follows:

```
private void CancelTasks()
{
    foreach (CancellationTokenSource tokenSource in MyTasks)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();                
    }
}
```

My worker function is as follows:

```
private void DoWork(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() => DoWork(tokenSource)));
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        bool dowork = true;
        while (dowork)
        {
            tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                dowork = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        countCompleted++;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {                
    }
}
```

In other posts that I have read, it has been suggested that  tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() is what sets the condition evaluated by the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled.

None of the examples that I have seen include the use of the:

```
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
}
```

However, without it the programs stops when i call the tokenSource.Cancel();

As it stands, when I do call the tokenSource.Cancel(), the Continuation with the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion runs, instead of the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled.

Clearly I'm not doing this correctly.

**Edit**:

Doing some further reading, I found a comment that states that:

"catch (OperationCanceledException) {} will set the task's status as RanToCompletion, not as Canceled"

So removing the catch (OperationCanceledException) {} allows the task's status to to be set to canceled, but the program breaks on the tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); but if I then continue through the break, the continuation task with the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled runs, which is good.

But how do I call tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() without allowing the program to break and while allowing the task status to be set to Canceled?

Comment: Instead of calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), check the IsCancellationRequested property and break out of your loop?

Comment: @Jon When I try that it does allow me to break out of the loop, but the task's status returns as RanToCompletion, not canceled, so the wrong continuation gets called.

Comment: Ok, I found another post where someone was having a similar issue; they said that they realized that they were starting the program in Debug mode, and when running it without debugging, it worked.  So I tried this, and everything seemed to work correctly.  But this means that I can't run in debug mode while working on the rest of the program without having to constantly deal with this exception being thrown.  Is there a way to get this to work properly while running in debug mode?

Comment: Just configure the debugger to not break on that exception type.  In the debug menu you can select exactly which exceptions you break for and which you don't.

Comment: @Servy thank you very much.  Never had to do that before, but that fixed my issue.  I think it a bit strange that letting the continuation task know that the task was canceled by way of throwing an exception instead of just setting a property, is the way that this thing works....but then again I am still pretty new to programming, so for all I know it could be an excellent way of doing it with benefits that are currently beyond me.   Anyway, thank you again for taking the time to help me learn something new.

Comment: Another way is `Tools > Options > Debugging > Then uncheck the option "Enable Just My Code"`. Found this tip here: [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx) in the comments at the very end of the sample code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comments above are correct in terms of the debugger and the options required to prevent the debugger breaking. However, the following should give you a better example of how to use continuations and indeed how to handle exceptions thrown from tasks within those continuations...

A continuation can find out if an exception was thrown by the antecedent `Task` by the antecedent task's exception property. The following prints the results of a `NullReferenceException` to the console

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write(ant.Exception());
```

If `task1` throws an exception and this exception is not captured/queried by the continuation it is considered unhandled and the application dies. With continuations it is enough to establish the result of the task via the `Status` keyword

```
asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Check task status.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            if (task.Exception != null)
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = task.Exception.InnerException.Message;
            else
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = "Operation failed!";
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you don't use continuations you either have to wait on the task in a `try`/`catch` block or query a task's `Result` in a `try`/`catch` block

```
int x = 0;
Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => 7 / x);
try
{
    task.Wait();
    // OR.
    int result = task.Result;
}
catch (AggregateException aggEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(aggEx.InnerException.Message);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That final catch (AggregateException aggEx) should handle multiple exceptions and nested AggregateExceptions with something like
foreach(Exception innerEx in aggEx.Flatten().InnerExceptions) {  Console.WriteLine( innerEx.Message); }