# How to await Tasks kicked off in Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I have a general question about how to keep track of an asynchronous task that is started when an object is disposed in .Net. I have a class designed around [Stephen Cleary's Dispose means cancel paradigm](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/async-oop-6-disposal.html). The problem is since Dispose is a void there is no way to keep track of that task directly.

I created another static class that has a list of tasks that allows me to do something like this at the end of my program to make sure all dispose tasks finish before the program exits.

```
    public async Task WaitForAllDanglingTasks(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (_dangling.Count > 0)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var t = await Task.WhenAny(_dangling.ToArray()).DetachContext();
            await _lock.WaitAsync(token).DetachContext();

            try
            {
                _dangling.Remove(t);
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.Release();
            }
        }

    }
```

Is this a good approach? Is there something better or is this even needed?

**EDIT:** Originally my problem was compounded by continuation task not executing and later I found that was due to a deadlock caused by my use of the SerialPort library. Please ignore all that follows. I left it so the comments make sense.

The problem is this blocks forever because most of my disposal tasks never run(usually one will run). Unfortunately I cannot share the code due to IP. But basically I have a socket that creates an object responsible for a long running RX task that polls the connection. Here is the pseudo code.

```
// This is in the Service class. ServiceTask is a public member that
// allows the socket to continue with other cleanup when it is done.
async Task StartService(args, token)
{
    ServiceTask = Task.Run(async () => await LongRunning(args, token))
                        .continuewith(t => cleanup(args));
    ServiceTask.TrackDisposal(); //adds to disposal Task list
    await LongRunningReady(token);
}

async Task LongRunning(args, token)
{
    using( var combined = CreateLinkedSource(_dispose.token, token))
    {
        DoWork(args);
    }
}

void Dispose()
{
    _dispose.Cancel();
}
```

I also read on [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) that he also suggests using await instead of ContinueWith. I do use await in most cases but with the long running task using Continuewith I can just call cancel on a token source and then the task ends naturally and then continues with the clean up. With await I would have to store some state in that class to clean up the stuff after awaiting for the ServiceTask variable.

I understand without the code this will be hard to diagnose. But I want to know if there is anything glaringly obvious that I am doing wrong that would cause the continuation tasks to not run.

It is also worth mentioning I am running from a console application and am using the AsyncContext from AsyncEx to support the async code. As well as, ManyConsole for the command line parsing and presentation.

Comment: At the end of `LongRunning` (or after the `await` in `StartService`, why don't you simply remove the task from the list? There doesn't seem to be a reason why you need to wait for Dispose to happen to do that.

Comment: I can't remove the task from the list there because I need to wait for the continuation not LongRunning itself. You made me think of a good point. I could just put the cleanup at the end of the LongRunning function but that doesn't solve the problem I am running into. I still have continuation tasks that are not executed causing the program to await them forever. Ie. The Socket attaches a cleanup continuation to the task after the service is ready.

Comment: `at the end of my program to make sure all dispose tasks finish before the program exits.` - but why? Why not just let the OS clean up?

Comment: @ProdigousRanger Do you have the correct `TaskContinuationOptions`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey Stephen, I am glad you saw this. I guess I think that is messy. And experience has taught me it is better to make sure everything is cleaned up as you expect rather than relying on the system. Also, I will likely come to some protocol shutdown procedures that I want to make sure run but don't need to hold up the active workflow processing the data by waiting for full disposal.

@IanMercer - Not using any continuation options. I want it to execute no matter what which is the default, right?

Comment: @ProdigousRanger - Do you observe the preceding `task.Status`? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15611686/224370

Comment: No I am not checking that status, but the continuation isn't called so I can't check it anyways.

Comment: I found the cause of the continuations not executing. I am using the SerialPort library to connect to a device. The Service task would hang waiting for the SerialPort.baseStream.readasync to throw the cancellation exception from the _dispose.cancel(). Problem is, the SerialPort library doesn't monitor that token unless it is actively reading from a device. So I took out the wait for the service to end and let other parts of my program close the port which then causes the read to throw cancellation. Should I update the question to just include keeping track of disposal tasks?

Comment: Yes, you should update your question.The LongRunning method is using the "using" block so you could implement your cleanup code in the object created by CreateLinkedSource. As an alternative you can put your cleanup code after  await LongRunningReady(token). After finishing the await that code will be executed.

Comment: Question updated, now just wanting to know what the best way to keep track of those tasks is and if it is even necessary.